# How to clear chart_bar selectedDatum in Flutter

Tags: flutter

I have a barchart ,when I click line it will navigate to new page.
I use model.selectedDatum.clear();
but when back to chart page , it is still select,it not working.

How can I set it unselect , when I back to chart page, thank you.

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
 return SizedBox(
 height: 400,
 child: charts.BarChart(
   _createSampleData(),
   animate: true,
   vertical: false,
   selectionModels: [
     charts.SelectionModelConfig(
         type: charts.SelectionModelType.info,
         changedListener: (charts.SelectionModel model) {
           if (model.hasDatumSelection) {
             int month = model.selectedDatum[0].index! + 1;
             Get.toNamed(RouteTable.expenseDetailList,
                    arguments: [_.currentYear, month, _.barSegmentIndex])?.then((value)=> 
                   model.selectedDatum.clear());
          }
        },)
  ],
    barRendererDecorator: charts.BarLabelDecorator<String>(
       labelAnchor: charts.BarLabelAnchor.end),
 ));
}
 List<charts.Series<double, String>> _createSampleData() {
 return [
  charts.Series<double, String>(
     id: 'Month',
      domainFn: (value, ix) => months[ix ?? 0],
      measureFn: (value, ix) => value,
      colorFn: ((value, ix) => charts.Color.fromHex(code: colors[index])),
    data: data,
    labelAccessorFn: (value, _) => nf.format(value))
 ];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Override [userManagedState](https://pub.dev/documentation/charts_flutter/latest/flutter/BaseChart/userManagedState.html) to handle [selectionModels](https://pub.dev/documentation/charts_flutter/latest/flutter/UserManagedState/selectionModels.html)

```
  final _myState = charts.UserManagedState<String>();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final chart = charts.BarChart(
      // ...
      // 1. override userManagedState
      userManagedState: _myState,
      selectionModels: [
        charts.SelectionModelConfig(
          changedListener: (model) {
            // 2. clear selectionModels
            setState(() {
              _myState.selectionModels[charts.SelectionModelType.info] = charts.UserManagedSelectionModel();
            });
          },
      ],
    );

    // ...
  }
```